# How do I cancel/strike out a line?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have drawn a long line with an arrow from one node to another. How do I strike out or cancel that line? What I want is something similar to how `\not` cancels `\to` in `A \not\to B`, e.g.

[image: What I want]

Here's what I got so far and what I want to mimic:

[image: Example of what I got]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (a) {\(A\)};
  \node (b) at (3,0) {\(B\)};
  \draw[->] (a) to (b);% I want this line cancelled/striked out
\end{tikzpicture}

\(A \not\to B\)

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `strike out` from the `shapes.misc` tikz library.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (a) {\(A\)};
  \node (b) at (3,0) {\(B\)};
  \draw[->] (a) -- node[strike out,draw,-]{} (b);% I want this line cancelled/striked out
\end{tikzpicture}

\(A \not\to B\)

\end{document}
```

This would be your modified code. And the result:

[image: cancelled arrow]

Comment: Both answers are good but I accepted this answer because it looks better in different directions and in conjunction with `[bend left/right]`.

Answer (score 11):

Not quite perfect perhaps.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (a) {\(A\)};
  \node (b) at (3,0) {\(B\)};
  \node (c) at (3,3) {\(C\)};
  \draw[->] (a) to node {\(\not\)} (b);
  \draw[->] (a) to node [sloped] {\(\not\)} (c);
\end{tikzpicture}

\(A \not\to B\)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I like this slightly better than my answer, doesn't require a library and looks exactly like the `\not\to` as well.

Comment: Can this be made to work properly when the line is not horizontal? E.g. when the coordinates of `(b)` is `(3,3)`.

Comment: Try adding `sloped` as an option to the `\not` node. I'll update the example shortly.

Comment: @TorbjornT. Cheers!