# Hardware diagrams latex,

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm looking [here](http://texample.net/tikz/examples/tag/block-diagrams/) for some examples of block diagrams, I was however wondering how can I insert a small "cut" in the signals arc and label it with the bitwidth.

Like the following

[image]

Comment: You can probably use a tikz decorations marking.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem maybe without "cut".

Comment: @marsupilam can you provide me a small example? (Just an arrow with a cut and a number, just as the picture I posted).

Comment: Similar: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31453/ For the number, you can add a new node, or add a `label` to the node providing the slanted line, e.g. `\draw[->] (a) -- node[strike out,draw,label=above:\tiny 4]{} (b);`. (requires the `shapes.misc` library).

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Let me try...

Comment: @TorbjørnT. It worked, the very last thing is that I'd like to attach a label, in the same fashion there's a number right next to the cut in my picture, can you give me this very last clue?

Comment: I did already in my last comment ... You'd just want to use `left` instead of `above` for the `label`: `label=left:\tiny 4`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "strike out" part has a good answer in [How do I cancel/strike out a line?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31453/how-do-i-cancel-strike-out-a-line/31455#31455)

To add the number you can for example add a `label` to the `node`, as in the first `tikzpicture` below. The second `tikzpicture` is exactly the same as the first, except that the options to the node is put in a `style`, for convenience.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (a) {\(A\)};
  \node (b) at (0,-1) {\(B\)};
  \draw[->] (a) -- node[strike out,draw,-,label=left:\tiny 4]{} (b);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[dashwithlabel/.style={strike out,draw,-,label=#1}]
  \node (a) {\(A\)};
  \node (b) at (0,-1) {\(B\)};
  \draw[->] (a) -- node[dashwithlabel={left:\tiny 4}]{} (b);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```