# Strike out arrow in commutative diagram using tikzcd

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, tikz-cd

I'd like to strike out the arrow between `C` and `D` in the following commutiative diagram defined using the `cd` Tikz library:

[image]

Building on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31455/59521) I came up with the following code that gives me the above result *without* the desired striked out arrow:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{cd}
    \usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \[
        \begin{tikzcd}
            A \arrow[leftrightarrow]{r} \arrow{d} & B \arrow{d} \\
            C \arrow[leftrightarrow,strike out]{r} & D
        \end{tikzcd}
        \]
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even easier than Enrico's solution...

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[main=ngerman,english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{babel,cd}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}
A \arrow[r,leftrightarrow] \arrow[d] & B \arrow[d] \\
C \arrow[r,"/"{anchor=center,sloped},leftrightarrow] & D
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

The `sloped` option is actually not needed in this case but comes in handy for vertical or curvy arrows.

[image]

Comment: Your solution does unfortunately not work on my machine when adding `\usepackage[main=ngerman,english]{babel}` at the end of the preamble.

Comment: `Missing \endcsname inserted. \end{tikzcd}` and `Package xcolor Error: Undefined color \penalty \@M \hskip \z@skip \discretionary {/}{}{/}\penalty \@M \hskip \z@skip "anchor=center,sloped'. I think the culprit is a tikzcd arrow in cell 2-1.`

Comment: @Christoph90  See updated answer.

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer, since it does the job and is more compact. However, I feel bad for not being able to accept egregs great answer too :)

Comment: @Christoph90 You should always accept the answer that you like most.  Otherwise the whole accepted-answer-business is pointless.

Answer (score 4):

A modification of https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51024/4427

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\tikzset{
  negate/.style={
    decoration={
      markings,
      mark= at position 0.5 with {
        \node[transform shape] (tempnode) {$/$};
      },
    },
    postaction={decorate},
  },
}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}
A \arrow[r,leftrightarrow] \arrow[d] & B \arrow[d] \\
C \arrow[r,leftrightarrow,negate] & D
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

There is no need to use a `figure` environment for a diagram. Also arrows are more uniformly specified in the above fashion.

[image]

Comment: `\arrow[r,leftrightarrow,"/" anchor=center]`, see my answer.