# Negating squiggle arrows in tikzcd

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-cd

I am trying to negate (some) squiggle arrows in tikzcd. I have tried "/" marking, etc. I can either get the appropriate squiggle arrow not negated, or I can get a normal arrow negated, but not a squiggle arrow negated. What I want is exactly what the code below produces except with the arced squiggle arrow from r to q negated.

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert=false]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=tiny]
& & & q \\
& & p \arrow[ur, rightsquigarrow] & \\
& r \arrow[ur] \arrow[bend left=50, rightsquigarrow, to=1-4] & & \\
\top \arrow[ur] & & &
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please always post full (but minimal) examples not sniplets like this. Here we have to add stuff to even test your code. You are more likely to get help in the first place if what you post is something others can copy and try as is.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to TeX.SE. Using this old [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/409286/strike-out-arrow-in-commutative-diagram-using-tikzcd) you can create a negate symbol with `"/"{anchor=center,sloped}`.

[image]

```
%% Compile and read me!
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd,amssymb}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
     \begin{tikzcd}[row sep=tiny]
& & & q \\
& & p \arrow[ur, rightsquigarrow] & \\
& r \arrow[ur] \arrow[bend left=50, "/"{anchor=center,sloped}, rightsquigarrow, to=1-4] & & \\
\top \arrow[ur] & & &
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```