# How to cross out an edge in a tikz tree

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have this tree:

```
% Decision tree
% Author: Stefan Kottwitz
% https://www.packtpub.com/hardware-and-creative/latex-cookbook
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
  treenode/.style = {shape=rectangle, draw},
  dec/.style={shape=rectangle,draw,fill=blue},
  chance/.style={shape=circle,draw,fill=red},
  end/.style={shape=rectangle}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
    grow                    = right,
    sibling distance        = 7em,
    level distance          = 12em,
    edge from parent/.style = {draw, -latex},
    every node/.style       = {font=\footnotesize},
    sloped
  ]
  \node [dec] {}
    child { node [chance, label=below:\$3] {} 
      edge from parent node [below] {L} }
    child { node [chance, label=below:\$8] {} 
      child { node [end] {\$8} 
        edge from parent node [above] {HD} } 
      child { node [end] {\$8}
              edge from parent node [above, align=center] {LD} }
              edge from parent node [above] {S} } %comes from root
      child { node [chance, label=below:\$1] {}
        edge from parent node [above] {M} } ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The picture currently looks like this:

[image]

I would like to "double cross out" the edge from the blue square to the top red circle (that is, put two short lines through the edge, perpendicular to the edge). The two lines should be between "M" and the red circle.

How can I do this in tikz?

Comment: I have tried: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31453/how-do-i-cancel-strike-out-a-line
But I can't use strike out in this type of setup, it seems.

Comment: One could create a [double strike] shape, although you mgiht want to set [minimum width] to something more than 2 [inner sep].

Comment: Hi @JohnKormylo, could you please elaborate on that and include code in an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On second thought, just use two `[strike out]`s.

Note, the size of the strike out is determined by the contents (text), or use [minimum width] and [minimum height].

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\tikzset{
  treenode/.style = {shape=rectangle, draw},
  dec/.style={shape=rectangle,draw,fill=blue},
  chance/.style={shape=circle,draw,fill=red},
  end/.style={shape=rectangle}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
    grow                    = right,
    sibling distance        = 7em,
    level distance          = 12em,
    edge from parent/.style = {draw, -latex},
    every node/.style       = {font=\footnotesize},
    sloped
  ]
  \node [dec] (AA){}
    child { node [chance, label=below:\$3] {} 
      edge from parent node [below] {L} }
    child { node [chance, label=below:\$8] {} 
      child { node [end] {\$8} 
        edge from parent node [above] {HD} } 
      child { node [end] {\$8}
              edge from parent node [above, align=center] {LD} }
              edge from parent node [above] {S} } %comes from root
      child { node (BB) [chance, label=below:\$1] {}
        edge from parent node [above] {M} } ;
  \path (AA) -- (BB) node[draw,strike out, pos=0.2] {}
                     node[draw,strike out, pos=0.25] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

---

This version creates a `[double strike]` shape.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\tikzset{
  treenode/.style = {shape=rectangle, draw},
  dec/.style={shape=rectangle,draw,fill=blue},
  chance/.style={shape=circle,draw,fill=red},
  end/.style={shape=rectangle}
}
\makeatletter
\pgfdeclareshape{double strike}
{%
  \inheritsavedanchors[from=rectangle]% % this is nearly a rectangle
  \inheritanchorborder[from=rectangle]%
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north}%
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north west}%
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north east}%
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{center}%
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{west}%
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{east}%
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{mid}%
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{mid west}%
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{mid east}%
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{base}%
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{base west}%
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{base east}%
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south}%
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south west}%
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south east}%
  \foregroundpath{
    \southwest \pgf@xa=\pgf@x \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
    \northeast \pgf@xb=\pgf@x \pgf@yb=\pgf@y
    \pgfpathmoveto{\southwest}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{\pgf@yb}}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{\pgf@ya}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\northeast}
    \pgfsetarrowsstart{}
    \pgfsetarrowsend{}
 }%
}%
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
    grow                    = right,
    sibling distance        = 7em,
    level distance          = 12em,
    edge from parent/.style = {draw, -latex},
    every node/.style       = {font=\footnotesize},
    sloped
  ]
  \node [dec] (AA){}
    child { node [chance, label=below:\$3] {} 
      edge from parent node [below] {L} }
    child { node [chance, label=below:\$8] {} 
      child { node [end] {\$8} 
        edge from parent node [above] {HD} } 
      child { node [end] {\$8}
              edge from parent node [above, align=center] {LD} }
              edge from parent node [above] {S} } %comes from root
      child { node (BB) [chance, label=below:\$1] {}
        edge from parent node [above] {M} } ;
  \path (AA) -- (BB) node[draw, double strike, pos=0.25] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: would it be okay to use--`\draw (1,0.5) node{} -- (1.1,.7);
\draw (1.1,0.5) node{} -- (1.2,.7);`  --or some such

Comment: @jsbibra - Seems like a lot of trial and error, but it is up to you.